# Is there an easier way to grasp Boothes algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, binary-operations

I'm sitting looking at video after video and nothing seems to be clicking with me on how to even start this problem I mean I think I convert it to the two's complement form even though it's already doing that. I'm trying  to use the algorithm on $1101(-5)$ x $0101 (5)$.